# Cause of "return outside of function" syntax error in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have problem in this code;

```
'return' outside function (<module1>, line 4)   <module1>   4
```

This code from book called **Learn the python hard way**; "Exercise 25: Even More Practice"

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
words = stuff.split(' ')
return words


def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return storred(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.php(0)
    print word

def sort_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence. """
    Words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prinits the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

any solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

in this function the `return` is not properly indented.

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
```

Comment: @user1653037 you're welcome, thanks us by accepting any of the answer you liked. see [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is off, try this:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words
```

Indentation is a key component of Python, unlike some other languages - so it is important to ensure that your code is properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation matters in python. From what you've pasted the last two lines here are NOT int the scope of break_words.

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
words = stuff.split(' ')
return words
```